# twisted - run in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted

new to python
new to twisted

My team wants me to make some existing code run in a seperate thread.

I've come up with a fictional example:

```
from twisted.internet import threads, reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
from time import sleep


class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.working = False

    def set_working(self, is_working):
        self.working = is_working
        print 'Flag set to {}'.format(is_working)

    @inlineCallbacks
    def do_worker_thread(self):

        # I want to make this call on the main thread
        self.set_working(True)

        # I want to do all this garbage on a separate thread and keep trucking on the main thread
        # This mimics some calls in the real code. There is a call to deferToThread and a try
        # except block there.
        def thread_proc():
            try:
                for i in range(0, 100):
                    print 'Step %d starting'.format(i)
                    self.execute_step(i)
            except Exception:
                print 'An exception happened'
        reactor.callInThread(thread_proc)

        # When the worker thread is done, I want to call back 'on_thread_work_done'

    def execute_step(self, num):
        sleep(num)
        print 'Worker thread: %d'.format(num)

    def on_thread_work_done(self):
        """I want to be called back when the worker thread is done"""
        self.set_working(False)

    @inlineCallbacks
    def do_main_thread(self):
        for c in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
            sleep(c)
            print 'Main thread: {}'.format(c)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    someClass = SomeClass()
    result = someClass.do_worker_thread()
    result.addCallback(someClass.do_main_thread())

    reactor.run()
```

The stuff on do_worker_thread currently runs on the main thread. I put a comment in there were I want it to run in a seperate thread. It is important that do_worker_thread returns immediately.

I expect the output to look something like:

```
Flag set to True
Step 0 starting
Main thread: a
Worker thread: 0
Worker thread: 1
Main thread: b
Worker thread: 2
Main thread: c
...
```

How can I alter what's in do_worker_thread, such that my set_working calls are on the main thread and it isn't set to False until the worker thread is done its work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving this a shot. It uses `callFromThread()` to schedule the work on the main thread.

```
from twisted.internet import threads, reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks, returnValue
from time import sleep


class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.working = False

    def set_working(self, is_working):
        self.working = is_working
        print 'Flag set to {}'.format(is_working)

    @inlineCallbacks
    def do_worker_thread(self):

        # I want to make this call on the main thread
        self.set_working(True)

        # I want to do all this garbage on a separate thread and keep trucking on the main thread
        # This mimics some calls in the real code. There is a call to deferToThread and a try
        # except block there.
        def thread_proc():
            try:
                for i in xrange(0, 10):
                    print 'Step {} starting'.format(i)
                    self.execute_step(i)
            except Exception:
                print 'An exception happened'

        yield threads.deferToThread(thread_proc)

        # When the worker thread is done, I want to call back 'on_thread_work_done'
        self.on_thread_work_done()

        returnValue(17)

    def execute_step(self, num):
        sleep(1)
        print 'Worker thread: {}'.format(num)

    def on_thread_work_done(self):
        """I want to be called back when the worker thread is done"""
        self.set_working(False)

    def do_main_thread(self):
        for i in [chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)]:
            print 'Main thread: {}'.format(i)
            sleep(1)

    def thread_done(self, result):
        print 'Thread done: {}'.format(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    someClass = SomeClass()
    # Schedule the threaded work
    result = someClass.do_worker_thread().addCallback(someClass.thread_done)
    # Schedule the main thread work
    reactor.callFromThread(someClass.do_main_thread)
    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [callFromThread](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorFromThreads.html#callFromThread) or [blockingCallFromThread](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.threads.html#blockingCallFromThread).